# Cin not prompting for Input in C++

Tags: c++11

Here why cin >> cin is not prompting for command line input. Visual Studio gives warning as C4552 `'>>': result of expression not used.`

```
int main()
    {
        int cin = 10;
        cin >> cin;
        cout << "print" << "    " << cin << endl;
    }
```

Comment: cin is a reserved keyword in c++.. Here, >> is being used as bit shift operator..

Comment: Give your integer some name other than `cin`. You are hiding `std::cin`. In `cin >> cin`, both mentions of `cin` refer to `int` local variable; that line means "shift the value of `cin` right by `cin` bits, and discard the result".